# Inner loop query not getting intended results

Tags: mysql, syntax, coldfusion

I have an issue with my cold fusion / mysql script.  It goes like this... i have two tables of info.

I have two tables; tbl_property and tbl_prop data.  The latter has data sheets relating to the properties that are in the other table...   Below is my query and hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong!

```
<cfquery name="getInfoByStreet" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT 
        tbl_property.prp_street_name,
        tbl_property.prp_street_suffix,
        tbl_property.prp_street_number,
        tbl_property.prp_street_direction,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_cat,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_ref,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_action,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_date,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_pdfFile,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_activity,
        tbl_prop_data.prp_ID,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_ID,
        tbl_prop_data.company_ID,
        tbl_prop_data.pd_status

    FROM  tbl_property

        INNER JOIN tbl_prop_data ON tbl_property.prp_ID = tbl_prop_data.prp_ID

        WHERE pd_active = 1 
        AND pd_date >= <cfqueryparam value="#begin#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
        AND pd_date <= <cfqueryparam value="#end#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
        <cfif activityS1 neq 0>AND pd_activity = '#activityS1#'</cfif>
        <cfif referenceS1 neq 0>AND pd_ref = '#referenceS1#'</cfif>
        <cfif actionS1 neq 0>AND pd_action = '#actionS1#'</cfif>
        <cfif statusS1 neq 0>AND pd_status = '#statusS1#'</cfif>
        AND pd_cat = '#form.cat#'

        GROUP BY prp_street_name ASC

</cfquery>
```

Here is a screenshot of the results it's giving me - and also the display code. What I want is to loop the records that are a match under the grouped streets...

```
<cfoutput query="getInfoByStreet" group="prp_street_name">

        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <th class="display">#prp_street_name# #prp_street_suffix#</th>
            <th class="display">Date</th>
            <th class="display">Reference</th>
            <th class="display">Action</th>
            <th class="display">PDF</th>
            </tr>
           <cfloop query="getInfoByStreet"> 
          <tr>
            <td height="41">#prp_street_number# #prp_street_direction# #prp_street_name# #prp_street_suffix#</td>
            <td>#DateFormat(pd_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")#</td>
            <td><span class="smallBlack">#getActionNow.name#</span></td>
            <td><span class="smallBlack">#getRefNow.name#</span></td>
            <td>#pd_pdfFile#</td>
          </tr>
          </cfloop>
        </table>
        </cfoutput>
```

[Front-end display of my posted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPuVV.jpg)

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but be sure to use cfqueryparam on *all* of the variable parameters, not just some of them ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `cfoutput` to loop through a group query you would just use a nested `cfoutput` to loop through the group.

`<cfoutput query="getInfoByStreet" group="prp_street_name">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <th class="display">#prp_street_name# #prp_street_suffix#</th>
        <th class="display">Date</th>
        <th class="display">Reference</th>
        <th class="display">Action</th>
        <th class="display">PDF</th>
        </tr>
        <cfoutput> 
            <tr>
            <td height="41">#prp_street_number# #prp_street_direction# #prp_street_name# #prp_street_suffix#</td>
            <td>#DateFormat(pd_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")#</td>
            <td><span class="smallBlack">#getActionNow.name#</span></td>
            <td><span class="smallBlack">#getRefNow.name#</span></td>
            <td>#pd_pdfFile#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </table>
</cfoutput>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply... I just tried that and it gave me the same results.  Could it be due to using "GROUP BY" in my sql query, as well as the CF group attribute on the display?

Comment: Interestingly... if I remove the GROUP BY line form the SQL statement, I get the results I need.  Well, it repeats one of the streets (records) but I'm going to look into if its misspelled or something

Comment: @JonJ. -  A common gotcha with grouped outputs is forgetting that the query results be sorted - **in the same order** - as the cfoutput grouping. For example, if the output uses `group="prp_street_name"` the cfquery must sort the results by that same column,  `... ORDER BY prp_street_name`

Comment: ... and that about does it.  Thanks all.

Comment: quick question... i just realized that when I sort by street name, I need two separate fields to make up the street name.   How would I accomplish this?

Comment: {CONCAT(tbl_property.prp_street_name, tbl_property.prp_street_suffix) AS "StreetName",}